# What does the term Unregistered mean on the user page?

Tags: support, profile-page

On some new users do I often see a grey text next to their name **`Unregistered`**. What does this mean?

Does it mean that the user has removed his/her account? Because I've seen people log-in after that they've been marked **`Unregistered`**.

Really what's the deal with this mark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They didn't add an openID. They can only log in by using the same browser.

[Source: Meta Stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68524/unregistered-user)